# Follow author on muti-user WordPress site

Tags: plugins, functions

How to add follow author function on muti-user based WordPress site?

I fount this page but couldn't get it to work or understand how he got this working.

[Making Wordpress author follow button, need missing ingredient](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180398/making-wordpress-author-follow-button-need-missing-ingredient)

Any advice?

thank you!

Comment: You have the answer already so you will have to better explain the question ;)

Comment: My advice: read the accepted answer. The bit on the custom taxonomy seems promising at first glance. If you don't understand taxonomies, read about that. If you have trouble understanding the answers, comment on the answers instead of creating a new question. If there is a specific point where you're stuck and you can formulate a concrete question, ask again, in a new question. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys. I wanted to make comment on the question but I couldn't cause of lack of reputation. I don't think I understand what is going on with that code cause I'm having trouble to combine all those code to make it work.

Comment: you should ask specifically about what you don't understand, hopefully after trying it out so you can point to the actual pain points. It is hard to know what is hard to understand without you saying it.